# How does towelroot (futex exploit) works

Tags: linux, security

There is a security issue in linux kernel, which affects most of android devices and basically allows any user to become root.

Since I am linux user for quite some time, I am very curious how this exploit works, especially how can I check whether my kernel in my PC (custom built) or on any of my servers, is vulnerable to this or not. Is there any source code (preferably documented) or details of the exploit so that I could see how it works? I could only find the generic information or closed source binaries that do exploit the bug and give you root if executed by any user, but no background information or details of which part of kernel has the flaw and how is it even possible to do this.

So far I found this interesting article http://tinyhack.com/2014/07/07/exploiting-the-futex-bug-and-uncovering-towelroot/ which explains that it uses stack hack, by calling certain syscalls in order to get something into a stack of `futex_queue`. While I understand how that works, I have no idea how changing anything in that stack can actually elevate privileges of current process. What I found interesting is, that this guy say that since kernel 3.13 something has changed and now different technique is needed to exploit this. Does it mean that this was **not even fixed and is still exploitable in recent kernel** that can be downloaded from kernel.org?

Comment: You might get a better response on http://security.stackexchange.com/ - ask and flag to migrate if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

As SilverlightFox said, the Security portion of stackexchange (http://security.stackexchange.com/) probably would be better for this, but here goes nothing.

From the sound of it, this hack appears to be a way to elevate any users' terminal/kernel for a given amount of time, which is, not to say the least, bad. My idea of how this sort of issue would work is a program that overloads the `futex_queue` by calling those said `syscalls` and then provides, temporarily, the user with superuser access.

I looked around at the link you provided and found that it does require remote login from `SSH` or similar procedures. In a console screenshot, it uses the line `gcc -o xpl xpl.c -lpthread`, which shows that this exploit is done in C. And a quote directly from the article:

> This is actually where the bug is: there is a case where the waiter is 
>   still linked in the waiter list and the function returns. Please note that  a kernel stack is completely separate from user stack. You can not 
>   influence kernel stack just by calling your own function in the userspace.  You can manipulate kernel stack value by doing  syscall.

In the image at http://www.clevcode.org/cve-2014-3153-exploit/, it shows the output of the `towelroot` exploit, testing the address limits and getting into the task structure to spawn a superuser shell. Also, in the tinyhack article, it gives a simple recreation of this exploit's base, so I'd recommend taking a look at that and working from it.

I don't know any clear form of testing if your system is vulnerable, so the best I can tell you is to try and harden your systems and do all you can to keep it protected. Anyway, I don't think that someone would easily get hold of server ports and logins to run this exploit on your system.

Cheers!